Ubuntu 24.04: How to change font size in Nautilus view panel?
I find the font size of file and folder names in Nautilus too small for me.
On Ubuntu 20.04, I could fix this with CSS on ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:
.nautilus-window .view {font-size: 20px}

However, this no longer works on Ubuntu 24.04.  How to achieve the same on 24.04?

This question is similar to: How do I change fonts and adjust their size?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham My question is very different from the one you reference.  In that case, the OP asks about system-wide font changes.  And the solutions offered do just that.  My question asks about one panel of a single application —Nautilus.  I do not want to change the font size anywhere else.  And I showed how I achieved this on Ubuntu 20.04.  I'm asking for how to do the same, narrow-scope change, in 24.04.

Did you just try zoomining in and out with Ctrl + and -?

That enlarges file and folder icons, not text.

The only other way I know is Settings -> Accessibility -> Seeing and select Large Text
